# SQL Server 2014 data source not works on SQL Server 2008 R2 reporting server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have created a SSRS report which has the data source that points to a database in **SQL Server 2014** version. It works locally (in 'preview' mode). Then, I deployed the same report in the Report server based on **SQL Server 2008 R2** version. When I tried to open the report, it gives me the following error.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) For more information about this error,
>   navigate to the report server on the local server computer, or enable
>   remote errors.

Do we have any workaround for this issue?

Comment: It seems there is no connection string

Comment: Navegante to ConnectionStrings and check it.

Comment: Data Source=*****(my instance);Initial Catalog=****(my database)
------------connection string is already set in the data source properties... @McNets

Comment: Did you check the datasource on the reportserver?

Comment: Also, make sure you can connect via SSMS from the 2008r2 server to the 2014 server. If not you may have to install the SQL Server 2012 Native Client on your 2008R2 box (note: there is no 2014 version). open this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065 expand in install instructions section and scroll down to the section MICROSOFT SQL SERVER CONNECTIVITY FEATURE PACK COMPONENTS and choose the 32 or 64bit download from there.

Comment: @Canadean_AS there is no need for any of these. There are no compatibility problems between these SQL Server versions.

Comment: ? No need to check you can connect from one machine to another? I disagree. It's a perfectly logical approach to tracking down the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Issue solved**

```
Cause for the Issue:
```

In the datasource connection properties, we had used **windows authentication** earlier. Because of that there were some connection problems.

```
Solution:
```

We tried creating a new user name and password for **SQL Server authentication** with required rights. This worked perfect!

Comment: That is not a solution, which makes this a bad answer. There is absolutely nothing wrong with Windows Authentication. If your RS service or execution account or the end user didn't have permission to connect to the database, just add the appropriate permission